# Python double simultaneous 'IF' conditions

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

Is it possible to loop through a list and, for each item in the list, go down two conditional IF paths?

For example, consider the below pseduocode:

```
for item in some_list:
    if some_variable == item:
        some_variable += 1
    else:
        some_variable -= 1
    andif some_other_varible == item:
        some_other_variable += 1
    else:
        some_other_variable -= 1
```

So each item is compared to two variables, and an action is performed on each variable depending on the value of the item.

Comment: Just change the `andif` to `if`. Either that or nest the if statements. I'm confused what you want.

Comment: Remove the `and` there and you should be fine. If not the, post is unclear

Comment: but if the first `if` condition is met, will the second `if` be fulfilled?

Comment: @Charon what do you mean by fulfilled? If/else block will be interpreted and, depending on conditional value `some_other_varible == item` either 'true' (below-if) block will be executed or 'false' (below-else) block will be executed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python if Else Problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478587/python-if-else-problems)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question, you simply need:

```
for item in list:
    if some_variable == item:
        some_variable += 1
    else:
        some_variable -= 1

    # Start new IF block
    if some_other_varible == item:
        some_other_variable += 1
    else:
        some_other_variable -= 1
```

Every time you open a set of IF statements, it is done with `if`. The condition next to the initial `if` is always checked. Other cases, like `elif` and `else`, are checked based on previous conditions in that set. Every time you use `if`, you're opening a new *set* of statements to check. The code above will check the first set, then move to the second set. So no matter which condition is true in the first set, `if some_other_varible == item` will always be checked.

A good rule of thumb is to consider opening one `if` block for every **logical decision** to be made. In this case, the first logical decision is "to either increment or decrement `some_variable` based on its value". The *second* logical decision is "to either increment or decrement `some_other_variable` based on its value". Therefore, check each with its own statement.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want the `andif` to be within the `else` of the `if` block above.

```
for item in list:
    if some_variable == item:
        somevariable += 1
    else:
        somevariable -= 1

        # Indented block is within 'else' above.
        if some_other_varible == item:
            some_other_variable += 1
        else:
            some_other_variable -= 1
```